# Using inflection point as threshold for segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUMb0n6UhSA) on image processing, I think the goal of the tutor is to achieve traditional threshold 
segmentation in order to separate the background and foreground of an image,
by fitting a polynomial curve to the intensity distribution of the image and 
finding an inflection point in the curve to use as a threshold.

Here is the code:

```
img = imread('rice.tif');
degree = 6;

%fitting intensity distribution
[frequency, intensity] = imhist(img);
[polynome, ~, mu] = polyfit(intensity, frequency, degree);
eval_fit = polyval(polynome, intensity, [], mu);
```

However, in the next code block:

```
%locate inflection point
[values, indices] = sort(abs(diff(eval_fit)));
[m, i] = min(diff(values))

thresh = indices(i)/255;
img_seg = imbinarize(img, thresh);
```

Specifically, the first two lines, I don't get, why use `abs`, `sort` if your going to derivate a second time?

Second, I searched on Google and I didn't find a similar approach, so I want ask is this approach good? Have you encountered it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn’t seen this one before.

I cannot wrap my head around the method. It is not looking for the inflection point of the polynomial fit. I think it is looking for a point where the derivative is most frequent. The minimum of the derivative of the sorted derivative values is a derivative value that occurs at least twice (the sort is such that it’s derivative is always non-negative). What this point means I don’t know. It is likely one of the maxima or minima of the polynomial fit?

The person in the video claims this is their method, meaning they invented it. Their [Google Scholar page](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=wan1hTcAAAAJ&hl=en) doesn’t seem to list a paper about this method though.

In any case, since the person in the video claims that their method produces a similar result to Otsu, I see no point in using an unproven method when Otsu is so simple and well established.

I also recommend you learn image processing from a good book rather than random tutorials on YouTube. There is lots of crap on YouTube and it often is hard to tell good and bad apart. Production values do not necessarily correlate with correctness.

Comment: "The minimum of the derivative of the sorted derivative values is a derivative value that occurs at least twice". Could you please explain this point?

Comment: @user7427260: The absolute of the derivative is a bunch of values >=0. Sorting them leads to a non-decreasing function. Its derivative is 0 where that function has two identical values. There are two identical values if the original function has the same derivative at two points. This is most likely to happen in places where the derivative is flat, but you can’t prove that, it’s just a likelihood. And what if there are multiple minima?